# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'IInterface' does not contain a definition for 'XMethod'

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have following interfaces and their inheritance:

```
public interface IBase1<T>  where T : struct
{}

public interface IBase2<T>  where T : struct
{
 T XMethod();
}

public interface IBaseInt : IBase1<int>, IBase2<int>
{}

public interface IBaseDecimal : IBase1<decimal>, IBase2<decimal>
{}

public interface IBaseInner<T>
{
void InnerMethod();
}
```

Then I have a class that implements IBaseInt and IBaseInner

```
public class BaseInt : IBaseInt, IBaseInner<int>
{
// some implementation code here

public int XMethod()
{
// implementation of int Xmethod
}

public void InnerMethod()
{
// implementation of InnerMethod
}
}
```

And other, that implements IBaseDecimal and IBaseInner

```
public class BaseDecimal : IBaseDecimal, IBaseInner<decimal>
{
    private readonly IBaseInt baseInt; //Injected by ninject
    public BaseDecimal(IBaseInt pBaseInt)
    {
        this.baseInt = pBaseInt;
    }

        public decimal XMethod()
        {
        // implementation of decimal XMethod
        }
        public void InnerMethod()
        {
            baseInt.XMethod(); // throws an exception, because don't recognize this method
        }
    }
```

but if I call through explicit cast:

```
(baseInt as IBase2).XMethod();
```

the exception is not thrown.

Could you please explain why is this happening?